# iterating over a huge list only once while counting syllables, sentences, and words in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I'm having some trouble getting started on a program to count the number of sentences, words, and syllables in a .txt. file.

Basically, I want to only iterate through the list once, during which I count everything, and then at the end I output it all. I don't want to iterate over it three times, one for each category (sentence, word, syllable.)

I have a good idea how to define the things I'm looking for.

For example, here's how I would approach checking for syllables:

```
(define (vowel? letter)
  (member? letter '(#\A #\E #\I #\O #\U #\Y #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y)))

(define (punctuation-mark? letter)
  (member? letter '(#\? #\. #\: #\; #\!)))

(define (syllable-start? character)
  (vowel? character))
```

I thought of using several functions similar to this that decide when to start counting, and boolean variables to decide when to stop. I'd use `syllable-start?` to see if I come across a vowel, and then I'd update some boolean, and stop when I hit something that's not a vowel (consonant, punctuation mark, something to mark the end of a syllable), re-updating the boolean. I'd use this same approach for the sentences and the words.

I'm struggling with the iteration though. I'm new to scheme, and I know how to use tail recursion but I'm uncomfortable with it.

I'm converting the file into a list of characters. Like this:

```
(define (count-everything filename)
  (define textstring(file->string filename))
  (define stringlist(string->list textstring))
```

I'm basically just confused on how to write the function above. How to start the iteration. I'm hoping someone could give me some advice while I search for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about "updating" and "iteration", you should pass the current state in parameters for recursive function calls.

Here's an example that should get you started - it counts the numbers of odd and even integers in a list and its result is a pair:

```
(define (odds-evens ls)
  (define (count l odds evens)
    (cond ((null? l) (cons odds evens))
          ((odd? (car l)) (count (cdr l) (+ 1 odds) evens))
          (#t             (count (cdr l) odds (+ 1 evens)))))
  (count ls 0 0))
```

Note how the current count of both kinds of elements is passed as parameters to the recursive procedure `count`.